# UpStream and DownStream of Nodes in NetworkX

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am new to Networkx in Python. I am trying to pick a node and get all nodes upstream and downstream of that node. For example, in the image below, for upstream node 2, I want to return nodes 1, 6 and 7. And for downstream node 2, I want to return 3, 4, 8, 9, and 5. The order of the output nodes do not matter. Is there a quick way to return them as a list?

[image]

Comment: given a node, how do you define which other nodes are upstream and which downstream?

Comment: Good question. I have a root node that I know its location in the graph. I call upstream from the given node to the root node and call downstream from the given node to another direction. Does this help?

Comment: Is it a directed graph?  and are there cycles?

Comment: Its an undirected graph. So, the "From" "To" order is messed up. Its not an easy task to convert it to directed graph.

Comment: Are there cycles?

Comment: Yes, there are some cycles but I know the root of the network as well as the leaf. So, I know paths should go from the root to the leaf. Is there an easy way to convert such an undirected graph to the directed graph? I used the shortest_path function to do ii and then created a directed graph but I still have some edges behinds that are not directed.

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming by upstream/downstream, this is a directed graph and you mean incoming/outgoing edges and their parents/children? You can use a breadth first tree search (`bfs_tree`).

See: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/traversal.html

Example:

```py
g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_edges_from([
    (7,6), 
    (6,2), 
    (6,1), 
    (1,2), 
    (2,4), 
    (2,3), 
    (3,4), 
    (4,8), 
    (4,9),
    (3,5)
])

upstream = [n for n in nx.traversal.bfs_tree(g, 2, reverse=True) if n != 2]
downstream = [n for n in nx.traversal.bfs_tree(g, 2) if n != 2]
```

But if I am misunderstanding, then you need to clarify what you mean by upstream/downstream, because the graph you showed looks undirected.

Comment: Thank you Dan. I tried traversal function but it did not work for me. The main reason is that my graph is not a directed graph. So, the order of nodes "From" "To" is messed up. I am trying to treat it as an undirected graph.

Comment: If your graph is undirected, then there's no concept of upstream/downstream, unless there are specific node properties that tell you that. In that case, use a breadth-first search.

Comment: I know the root node. That can help to define upstream and downstream. It will be enough to solve it?

Comment: If it's an acyclic graph and you know the root node, you could define the directions that way. If there are cycles, you're out of luck unless you can build the directed graph another way.  Traverse your graph and construct it as a directed graph and that may get what you're looking for, but I couldn't tell you without more detail on the graph itself.

You can use these functions to find cycles:
https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/cycles.html

Comment: Thank you Dan, Let me go over it. I will keep you posted.

Comment: Dan, there are some cycles but I know the root of the network as well as the leaf. So, I know paths should go from the root to the leaf. Is there an easy way to convert such an undirected graph to the directed graph? I used the shortest_path function to do it and then created a directed graph but I still have some edges behinds that are not directed.

Comment: I couldn't say without seeing the data.